# <context:load-time-weaver/> dynamically

Tags: spring, aspectj

I am looking for a way to enable aspectJ load time weaving dynamically, say based on whether a JNDI property is true.

Basically, (context:load-time-weaver) have this tag conditionally.

Any quick way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Spring profiles](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/):

```
<beans profile="production">
    <context:load-time-weaver />
</beans>
```

If the profile name is `production`, LTW will be enabled. Otherwise the whole inner block is ignored. I am not sure if profile can be set using JNDI variable, but there are multiple other approaches, e.g.: JVM property, environment variable, web context parameter or you can set them programmatically.

Comment: It works fine if I use system variable "spring.profiles.active" to activate the profile, but doesn't work when I try to use JndiPropertySource programmatically to fetch the active profiles list through JNDI. Probably because when I add the source, it's too late to activate load time weaving?

Comment: @Sumedh: I don't think it's too late. Unfortunately I don't have much experience with Spring profiles, thus I'm not sure if they integrate with JNDI variables.